# Laravel Page Continuously Loading

Tags: php, laravel

I have downloaded my laravel application (careers) from cpanel and placed it in htdocs folder, 
when i browse `localhost/careers/login` the page continuously start loading. There is no error reported in the logs folder.

I have tried all the possible commands and steps, but still same issue.

**.env File:**

```
APP_NAME="VTBPO HRM"
APP_ENV=local
APP_KEY=base64:zipDoVJPTWnMlivfnxyp6MTeqE2UanRCEaXZsWwm7pA=
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_URL=localhost
```

**Commands/Steps I Followed:**

```
    php artisan config:cache // clear config cache
    php artisan config:clear // clear config cache
    php artisan cache:clear // clear cache
    php artisan route:cache // clear route cache
    php artisan view:clear // clear view cache

    chmod 777 -R storage/
    php -S localhost:8000 -t public/
```

I have tried all these steps but still facing the same issue, i will appreciate if someone could guide me through this.

Comment: Try serving in different port:-
php -S localhost:3000 -t public/

Comment: It didn't worked.

Answer (score 1):

I think it for permission issues

```
sudo chmod -R 777 your_project_directory/storage
```

and

```
sudo chown -R www-data:www-data you_project_directory
```

Comment: Will you please guide me about "your_project_directory"? it should be the path to my directory? I mean like this "C:\xampp\htdocs\careers\storage"?

Comment: yes.open your terminal from your project folder. & just write pwd .then get your path of directory